# UDP socket binding windows 10 vs windows 7

Tags: c, sockets, binding, windows-7, windows-10

I have been trying to bind a socket in windows 10 both in c (using ***cygwin***) and python.

Both languages do not work, the c implementation returns: `**"bind: Cannot assign requested address"**`.

I'm not sure what the problem is since running the same code on windows 7 gives no problem.

Does anyone have any clue?

I include the c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>   //printf
#include<string.h>  //memset
#include<stdlib.h>  //exit(0);
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h> //close

#include <sys/errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    //initialize socket and structure
    int socket_info;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    //create socket
    socket_info = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (socket_info == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket.");
        exit(0); 
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //Use this ip address 
    char pc_ip_addr[] = "192.168.100.47";
    inet_pton(AF_INET, pc_ip_addr, &server.sin_addr.s_addr);

    //Destination port
    server.sin_port = htons( 12345 );

    //Binding address to this server
    if (bind(socket_info, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0) {
        perror("Binding error");
        exit(0); 
    }

    puts("Server binding success.");

    close(socket_info);
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure, that the IP `192.168.100.47` is indeed assigned to your windows 10 host. Does it work with `INADDR_ANY`?

Comment: From you comments in code it seems that you might be thinking backwards. `bind` does not cause your interface to use a given address. It also does not "bind the address to the server". It binds the server socket to the address. Which means there must be an interface with that address in your machine.

Comment: On a side note, `inet_pton(..., &server.sin_addr.s_addr);` should be `inet_pton(..., &server.sin_addr);` instead. For `AF_INET`, `inet_pton()` expects an `in_addr*` not a `uint32_t*`. Though in this case, the address of the `in_addr` and the address of its `uint32_t` field are the same address, but you should not rely on that.